# Proxy not working via (.PAC file) for specific app

Tags: proxy, pac

I'm having some strange problem, In company we moved to new proxy. And we applied it via .PAC file to user machines. Internet working fine, but MS Teams not working.

But when I set manually on PC **Proxy Server setup option** `http://proxy.example.com` of new proxy Ms Teams working
but by .PAC file not working

**.PAC file**

```
function FindProxyForURL (url, host)
{
url = url.toLowerCase();
host = host.toLowerCase();

    // NetBIOS-names
    if (isPlainHostName(host)) return "DIRECT";

    // internal DNS-suffixes
    if (shExpMatch(url,"*pca.com*") ||
     shExpMatch(url,"*kkb.com*") ||
     shExpMatch(url,"*example.com*") ||
     shExpMatch(url,"*example.com*") ||
     shExpMatch(url,"*example.com") ||
     shExpMatch(url,"*example.com*") ||
     return "DIRECT";

    if (shExpMatch(host,"127.0.0.1") ||
       shExpMatch(host,"100.*.*.*") ||
       shExpMatch(host,"172.16.*.*") ||
       shExpMatch(host,"192.168.*.*"))
       return "DIRECT";

if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "10.108.0.0", "255.252.0.0"))
return "PROXY proxy.example.com:3128; " +
"PROXY proxy.example.com:3128";
}
```

[image: PC proxy settings]

Answer (score 0):

Try to download your PAC file with a browser (without proxy). If you can't download it, the system can't access it.

Make sure the PAC file is working. You can test it with something like this: https://thorsen.pm/proxyforurl

I don't know if it is intended, but your proxy in the settings varies from the one in your PAC file.
If you want us to help you and find errors in your configuration, your information needs to be accurate.